# Write ONE code-base for Mobile and Desktop?

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications, mobile, cross-platform

I am interested in writing a single code-base for an application, that will work across iPhone, Android and Blackberry mobile devices as well as on desktop browsers like Firefox, IE and Chrome.
Is this possible or I am just dreaming?

Also, another limitation I have, is that I want to use a .Net programming language for this app in combination with HTML5, jQuery and CSS3.

Technology changes very rapidly nowadays  by every month, and I was wondering if this is possible now in Nov, 2012. I knew it was not possible in May, 2012.

Comment: I want to develop a single app. NOT games.

Comment: A web app would fit the requirements as you've described them.

Comment: therefromhere - What development IDE I would use for what you just said. Is there something on the web describing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they will render Html Table's fine.. There is really little limitation if any when using html. The only restrictions are if the browser supports Html 4.x which most now support HTML 5 so you will be alright. Your CSS will be the main thing that determines how the items are rendered on different platforms nothing else.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, you can always use C. A library function written in C can be accessed from within Objective C on the iPhone, via JNI on Android and via CGI or most server-side scripting languages on a webserver (Ruby, PHP).

I dont know of any library that would generate user interfaces for all these platforms and I dont think that would even make sense because user interaction will be so much different.

In case you want to create a game, have a look at the Unity Game Engine which runs on a number of different platforms.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to include that I would want to use a .Net programming language like c# or f# or vb.net.

Comment: Hmmm is this purely browser based for Android, Iphone, Blackberry, and desktops??? If it's browser based your not as restricted and will mostly only face having to provide a mobile and desktop format.

Comment: Adding to what I have said.. If it is purely browser based then the user will be accessing server side data provided by the site. I do know for certain that an entire web based management system I wrote in MVC 3 works fine through android and since it is HTML I think it is safe to assume that all phone with mobile browsers will work fine with it provided I provide the appropriate styles. You would build your web based app and get it live on a web server then simply browse to it from the phone..

Comment: Skindeep - Thanks. So, mobile browsers nowadays are powerful enough to render a grid, that gets rendered as a 'HTML TABLE'? If you could please post this in a separate post, so I could give you points/mark it as an answer.